# how to uninstall custom database table in drupal 6

Tags: 6, hooks, database

I want to create custom table for my custom module "custom_module_table"

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function custom_module_install() {

 drupal_install_schema('custom_module');

}

function custom_module_schema() {
    $schema = array();
    $schema['custom_module_table'] = array(
    'description' => t('The base table for iframe site builder nodes.'),
    'fields' => array(
      'sid' => array(
        'description' => t('The primary identifier for a iframe site builder.'),
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => t('The {node_type} of this node.'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => ''),

      'uid' => array(
        'description' => t('The primary identifier for a iframe site builder.'),
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE),

      'created' => array(
        'description' => t('The site_password of this node, always treated a non-markup plain text.'),
        'type' => 'timestamp',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 'NOW()'),
      ),
    'unique keys' => array(
      'sid'     => array('sid')
      ),
    'primary key' => array('sid'),
    );

    return $schema;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function custom_module_uninstall() {
     drupal_uninstall_schema('custom_module_table');
}
```

This code write in .install file in my module and table is successfully created
but when I am uninstall the module, table is not delete.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the DB user has "DROP" privilege.
2. try to use direct query instead of *drupal_uninstall_schema*

update_sql('DROP TABLE {custom_module_table}');